# Linked list node-level locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to C++ threading library. I would love to get some comments on how to improve this code (if there are possible bugs, I would appreciate that feedback too). In particular, I want to refactor the code for the methods of the linked list:

1. How to return unique_lock in a function so that it didn't unlock the mutex under the hood?
2. Are there possible deadlocks with the lock acquisition that takes place in my code?
3. Does it look correct?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <thread>
   #include <mutex>
   #include <atomic>
   #include <vector>

   using namespace std;

   /*
   * This is an implementation of a singly linked list with node-level locks to
   * ensure mutual exclusion. The structure looks like this:
   *          head_ -> node_0 -> node_1 -> ... -> node_n -> tail_
   * Note that head_ and tail_ are dummy nodes.
   */
   class LockBasedLinkedList {
   public:
       // Initialize head_ to point to tail_ (empty list).
       LockBasedLinkedList() {
           tail_ = new Node(0);
           head_ = new Node(0, tail_);
       }

       /*
       * Insert a node with value val at position pos.
       *
       * To ensure mutual exclusion, the locks of the current node and the
       * previous nodes must be acquired for insertion to work. As soon as the
       * locks are acquired the code does roughly the following:
       *
       *      | prev -> node | prev -> node | prev    node |
       *      |              |          ^   |   v      ^   |
       *      |   new_node   |   new_node   |   new_node   |
       */
       void insert(int val, int pos) {
           Node *new_node = new Node(val);
           Node *prev = head_;
           unique_lock<mutex> prev_lk(prev->m);
           Node *node = prev->next;
           unique_lock<mutex> node_lk(node->m);
           for (int i = 0; i < pos && node != tail_; i++) {
               prev = node;
               node = node->next;
               prev_lk.swap(node_lk);
               node_lk = unique_lock<mutex>(node->m);
           }
           new_node->next = node;
           prev->next = new_node;
       }

       /*
       * Erase the node at position pos.
       *
       * To ensure mutual exclusion, follow the steps from insert(). As soon as
       * the locks are acquired the code does roughly the following:
       *
       *    (*)     (*)            (*)     (*)            (*)
       *  | prev -> node -> next | prev    node -> next | prev ---------> next |
       *  |                      |   v--------------^   |                      |
       *
       * (*) highlights the nodes whose locks are acquired.
       */
       void erase(int pos) {
           Node *prev = head_;
           unique_lock<mutex> prev_lk(prev->m);
           Node *node = prev->next;
           unique_lock<mutex> node_lk(node->m);
           for (int i = 0; i < pos && node != tail_; i++) {
               prev = node;
               node = node->next;
               prev_lk.swap(node_lk);
               node_lk = unique_lock<mutex>(node->m);
           }
           if (node == tail_) {
               return;
           }
           prev->next = node->next;
           node_lk.unlock();
           delete node;
       }

       int get(int pos) {
           Node *prev = head_;
           unique_lock<mutex> prev_lk(prev->m);
           Node *node = prev->next;
           unique_lock<mutex> node_lk(node->m);
           for (int i = 0; i < pos && node != tail_; i++) {
               prev = node;
               node = node->next;
               prev_lk.swap(node_lk);
               node_lk = unique_lock<mutex>(node->m);
           }
           if (node == tail_) {
               return 0;
           }
           return node->val;
       }

   private:
       struct Node {
           int val;
           Node *next;
           mutex m;

           Node(int val_, Node *next_ = nullptr) : val(val_), next(next_) {}
       };

       Node *head_, *tail_;
   };

   void testNThread(int n) {
       const int N = 10;
       vector<thread> threads(n);
       LockBasedLinkedList lst;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           threads[i] = thread([i, &lst, N]() {
               for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                   lst.insert(i, 0);
               }
           });
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           threads[i].join();
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < N * n; i++) {
           int val = lst.get(0);
           lst.erase(0);
           cout << val << " ";
       }
       cout << "\n";
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       int n = 10;
       if (argc >= 2) {
           n = atoi(argv[1]);
       }
       testNThread(n);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congratulations — I think this is the first concurrency-related code I've reviewed on CodeReview in which I have *not* managed to find any concurrency-related bugs! It looks like a solid implementation of "hand-over-hand" traversal. (Now that I've said that, I bet someone else will find a bug. :))

First, a few stylistic nitpicks:

```
using namespace std;
```

Never! Just write `std::vector<std::thread>` if that's what you mean. The small space savings isn't worth dealing with all the people like me who'll tell you over and over not to write `using namespace std;` at global scope. :)

---

```
const int N = 10;
```

Make this `constexpr int N = 10;` and you won't need to capture a copy of it in your lambda. (EDIT: Looks like I'm wrong. MSVC captures a copy in either case; GCC and Clang don't-capture in either case, unless the lambda takes the address of its copy, in which case they both capture. What a mess.)

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}
```

Prefer to write this with a ranged for loop:

```
for (auto&& thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}
```

(EDIT: I use `auto&&` because it Always Works. You could use `auto&` or `const auto&` as appropriate, but then you'd have to worry about which one was appropriate in each given case, and so would your code-reviewer. `auto&&` Always Works.)

---

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;
    mutex m;

    Node(int val_, Node *next_ = nullptr) : val(val_), next(next_) {}
};
```

Defaulted function arguments are the devil. And, completely independently, so are implicit conversions! I would prefer to write this as:

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next = nullptr;
    mutex m;

    explicit Node(int val_) : val(val_) {}
    explicit Node(int val_, Node *next_) : val(val_), next(next_) {}
};
```

or even

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *next;
    mutex m;

    explicit Node(int val_) : Node(val_, nullptr) {}
    explicit Node(int val_, Node *next_) : val(val_), next(next_) {}
};
```

(EDIT: I put `explicit` on every constructor, even the multi-argument ones, unless I have a specific reason that I *want* implicit conversion. In C++11, an implicit multi-arg constructor permits e.g.

```
void foo(const Node&);
Node bar() {
    foo({1, nullptr});
    return {1, nullptr};
}
```

and I consider preventing that "feature" to be a good thing.)

---

Okay, now for the serious stuff.

```
void erase(int pos);
```

This is a really weird API for a linked list. For one thing, even for a non-concurrent linked list, you're turning "erase a node" into an O(n) operation. More importantly for a *concurrent* linked list, I can't see how this operation is useful at all! Suppose some thread says "please erase the 42nd element." How does it even know what the 42nd element *is*, given that any other thread could modify the list at any time?

---

Your use of raw `new` and `delete` looks safe to me, but it would be a lot easier to verify its safety if you just didn't use raw `new` and `delete`! Consider this trivial rewrite of `insert`:

```
void insert(int val, int pos) {
    auto new_node = std::make_unique<Node>(val);
    Node *prev = head_;
    unique_lock<mutex> prev_lk(prev->m);
    Node *node = prev->next;
    unique_lock<mutex> node_lk(node->m);
    for (int i = 0; i < pos && node != tail_; i++) {
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
        prev_lk.swap(node_lk);
        node_lk = unique_lock<mutex>(node->m);
    }
    new_node->next = node;
    prev->next = new_node.release();
}
```

Only two lines changed, but now it's *obvious* that we never leak memory...

---

...except in the destructor of `LockBasedLinkedList`, which (being defaulted) just leaks every node remaining in the list! Was that intentional, or an oversight?

---

Also consider the behavior of

```
LockBasedLinkedList a;
auto b = a;
```

This certainly doesn't do what you want. What *do* you want it to do? If the answer is "I want it not to compile," then you should `=delete` your copy operations:

```
LockBasedLinkedList(const LockBasedLinkedList&) = delete;
LockBasedLinkedList& operator=(const LockBasedLinkedList&) = delete;
```

(EDIT: Deleting your copy operations will automatically cause your move operations to not-get-implicitly-generated. The full rules are a mess: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512883/1424877). Feel free to explicitly `=delete` your move operations too, if you want.)

---

In `get`:

```
    if (node == tail_) {
        return 0;
    }
```

How would your user distinguish the `0` that means "no such node" from the `0` that means "this node exists and has value `0`"? I would strongly recommend designing your API so that this distinction is obvious to the user. For example:

```
std::optional<int> get(int);
```

---

> How to return unique_lock in a function...?

I think this is related to your `get` API, yeah? That is, maybe you want something like

```
LockedNodePointer get(int);

class LockedNodePointer {
public:
    LockedNodePointer(std::nullptr_t) : ptr_(nullptr) {}
    Node& operator*() const { return *ptr_; }
    Node& operator->() const { return ptr_; }
private:
    friend class LockBasedLinkedList;
    using Lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;
    explicit LockedNodePointer(Lock lk, Node *ptr) : lk_(lk), ptr_(ptr) {}
    Lock lk_;
    Node *ptr_;
};
```

This is an even cleaner way to distinguish "node with value `0`" from "no such node."

---

It would also be interesting to consider: do you need a version of your `get` member function that is `const`-qualified? (Getting an element doesn't really modify the list, right?)

Do you need two overloads of `get` — one `const` and one non-`const`?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this answer. I have a few questions regarding your comments, and since I am still dabbling in C++11/14/17 features, please correct me if I make wrong assumptions:

Comment: 1. When I make a `constexpr`, its value gets computed during compile time rather than run time. Why does that make my threads see `N` within their bodies considering that I didn't capture that value for the thread function to access?

Comment: 2. You use `auto &&` to iterate over the elements in a vector that I initialized in memory (which means it's an lvalue (?)). So wouldn't `auto &` suffice? I assume that I should use `auto &&` in case like `for (auto &&s : vector<string>{"hello", "world"}) cout << s << " ";` but even then it's unclear to me why I would not use an lvalue reference `const auto &` which achieves the same thing?

Comment: 3. When you say implicit conversion for contructors, you mean cases where I have a constructor `A(int n) { /* do something with n */ }` and the user initializes with `A a = 5;` which presumably will invoke the constructor I defined above? If that's the case, am I right that we only need `explicit` for the one-argument constructors?

Comment: 4. Regarding `erase`, it was a late night choice because I just wanted to get something working. This is a personal project after I read papers on lock-free data structures and just wanted to write a lock-based one with a finer granularity than a mutex over the whole list as a baseline for later comparisons. I should probably rethink what I want my `erase` to do...

Comment: 5. I see how you are using `unique_ptr` to avoid potential memory leak problems. My question would be if in the future I develop a cursor/iterator to the nodes in my list, should I switch to `shared_ptr` then (because a node can be referenced by the `next` field of the previous node as well as by the iterator)? Why should I not switch to them right away? Is that due to performance issues?

Comment: 6. Yeah I need to write a destructor... If I switch completely to `unique_ptr` though, would it essentially mean that I do not have to free memory anywhere? I assume that if a Node get destructed it calls destructor on each of its member which will destroy the `unique_ptr` to the next node in my `struct Node`? So things will get destroyed recursively.

Comment: 7. As for the deleted functions, would I be right to say that if I don't specify anything, C++ just uses default functions which I presume copy the fields one by one, invoking necessary copy/move assignments (or constructors?) on the fields if they are not simple types? Then do I not also want `LockBasedLinkedList(LockBasedLinkedList &&) = delete;` and `LockBasedLinkedList &operator=(LockBasedLinkedList &&) = delete;` for completeness?

Comment: 8. I just took a look at `std::optional`. It is pretty neat, thanks!

Comment: 9. I see your point of making a new kind of node that represents a locked Node. I will switch to that once I have somewhat of a working linked list. However, for now my idea was make a function that does what the first ten lines of my code for each method do, returning the locks and the pointers to the caller. I have an idea how to do that but am unsure if that's the cleanest way. I acquire the lock with `unique_lock` in the callee and then relase it with assignment to the caller's reference to its `unique_lock`. Is that a good idea?

Comment: 10. I will have to think about design for this data structure again is what I got from the design comments you left.

Comment: If any of the questions can be answered by reading some resource online, please let me know where and don't bother typing the answers. You already did more than I expected from a code review.

Comment: Yeesh, 12 messages in my inbox! I've answered 1, 2, 3, 7 in edits. (5) `shared_ptr` does reference counting with control blocks; don't use it unless that's what you want. (6) If you change `Node *next` to `std::unique_ptr<Node> next`, then you're right; but that's probably unwise. See [Herb Sutter's CppCon 2016 keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: (9) I think you misunderstood my code; `LockedNodePointer` doesn't represent a "new kind of node." It represents a pointer to an existing (locked) node, and bundles up the pointer and the lock into a single class. This gives you a clean way to "return the lock and the pointer to the caller": you just write `LockedNodePointer get(int i) { ... }`. And then the caller can do `auto ptr = get(42); if (ptr != nullptr) myvalue = ptr->val;` safely. Because the `ptr` holds within itself the lock on the pointed-to node. And when the caller drops the `ptr`, the lock gets freed.

Comment: Is there a situation in which `auto&&` can cause problems?

Comment: @bruglesco: Nope! `auto&&` Always Works. Even for iterating over a `vector<bool>`, which is the canonical example where `auto&` won't work. https://godbolt.org/z/hH6HxC

Comment: Do you use lvalue references when you want to maintain constness?

Comment: @bruglesco: No. *Maintaining* constness is handled automatically by `auto&&` — it's the same mechanism as perfect forwarding. Iterate over a const container, and naturally you get const references to the elements. If you want to *add* constness, then (1) personally I wouldn't, but (2) if you're desperate, you could iterate `for (auto&& elt : std::as_const(container))`. EDIT: and I should add that `vector<bool>` is DEEPLY weird https://wandbox.org/permlink/hYrT51I1dYXXiKpl