# Specialized ConcurrentLinkedList

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list, concurrency

I need a concurrent data structure with the following properties:

- Low overhead for enumeration
- Insert only at end.
- Removal from any point.
- Enumeration should be safe with concurrent writing
- Enumeration does not require the list to be in a constant state
- Not a problem if I enumerate over removed items

I have designed the following linked list class which should meet my requirements.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal class ConcurrentLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<Node<T>> {
    private readonly BaseNode<T> _root;
    private BaseNode<T> _end;
    public ConcurrentLinkedList() {
        _end = _root = new BaseNode<T>();
    }

    public Node<T> Insert(T value) {
        var node = new Node<T>(value);
        lock (node) {
            lock (_end) {
                node.Previous = _end;
                _end = _end.Next = node;
                return node;
            }                
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Node<T> node) {
        lock (node.Previous) {
            lock (node) {
                if (node.Next == null) {
                    if (node.Previous.Next != node) return;
                    node.Previous.Next = null;
                    if (_end == node) _end = node.Previous;
                } else {
                    lock (node.Next) {
                        if (node.Previous.Next == node) node.Previous.Next = node.Next;
                        if (node.Next.Previous == node) node.Next.Previous = node.Previous;
                    }                                    
                }
            }        
        }
    }


    public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator() {
        for (var current = _root.Next; current != null; current = current.Next) {
            yield return current;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

internal class BaseNode<T> {
    internal volatile Node<T> Next;
}

internal class Node<T> : BaseNode<T> {
    internal BaseNode<T> Previous;

    public T Value { get; }

    public Node(T value) {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I am aware the calls is vary easy to misuse but as it is only for internal use i am not concerned about this. I am considering making the all the class private subclass to ensure that there is no accidental misuse.

In the code all the writing is in a lock but there are shared volatile which are read out of lock. Apart from the possibility of enumerating deleted nodes, is there any other danger with this?

For the locking, I lock no all the node being changed. This should allow other parts of the list to be concurrency modified, the list can get long. Is this sufficient?

To avoid deadlock I always lock from the lowest node to the last.

Is the provided locking sufficient to protect the `_end` field? I believe that according to the logic used the current `_end` will always be locked when changing the value of `_end`. Is this sufficient?

Is this code trying to be too clever and would it better to either:

- have one write lock and continue using the volatile for reading.
- use a standard `ReadWriteLock` for the whole list.

Comment: Initially `_end` points to the same object as `_root`. `_end.Next` is assigned to.

Comment: Ahh, mistook it for head+tail, not that version, `readonly _root` is the only internal-persistent node, `_end` is just a *pointer* to last node. My apologies.

Comment: There is currently [similar idea for review implemented in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/207626/linked-list-node-level-locking) (a bit different, having both head+tail nodes, but with same *hand-over-hand* locking as Quuxplusone named it).

Answer (score 6):

## EDIT: Possible race condition

I would not accept this code to production without proper documentation containing good proof, that it works as expected. `lock (node.Previous)` could get interrupted by another `Remove` changing `node.Previous` after it was passed to `Monitor.Enter` which smells too much (it will lock removed node instead of the one it should). Changing the order of locks may introduce dead-lock (starvation).

Let us start by `Insert(1); Insert(2); Insert(3)` and then call `Remove` from three different threads. 3rd thread will call `lock (node.Previous)` which contains two parts - first fetching `node.Previous` and then calling `Monitor.Enter`. Let us suspend this `Remove(3)` in between - fetching `Node(2)`, but not yet calling `Monitor.Enter` (or suspend inside, but before it can do anything). Let us now finish `Remove(2)`, which will change `Node(3).Previous = Node(1)`. Let us continue 3rd thread, **which will lock removed `Node(2)` (instead of `Node(1)`)** and `Node(3)` reaching line `node.Previous.Next = null`. It won't crash here because `lock` introduces memory barrier (thus `node.Previous` will trully read `Node(1)`, not the locked `Node(2)`). Let us suspend 3rd thread here and start 1st thread calling `Remove(1)`, locking `_root`, `Node(1)` passing `if (node.Next == null)` going to `else lock (node.Next)`. Let us now suspend this thread and continue in 3rd thread that was about to do `node.Previous.Next = null`. **Compiler will probably cache `node.Next` in 1st thread, but what if it does not? `lock (null)`.** We could rewrite it (`var next = node.Next; if (next == null) { ... } else lock (next)`), now 1st thread will block until 3rd finishes, but is still left with `node.Next = null` possibly crashing in `if (node.Next.Prevous == node)` and even if we change that to `if (next.Previous == node) next.Previous = ...` it changes state of removed node which you could try to remove again... and it is all looking like not worth the effort.

**Single [`ReaderWriteLockSlim`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim) is safe to use and the performance will still probably be good enough. Using lock only for writing (`Insert`, `Remove`) and leaving `GetEnumerator` without any locking may still be possible - read my original answer (3rd point).**

## Original answer

I will leave my original answer here as there may still be some valuable information, but I do not trust the locking now. It won't dead-lock and although I cannot proove race-condition corrupting the state (not one that could not be fixed), I myself will never use such collection, unless somebody can describe unbreakable proof that it is safe.

---

## My reasoning why the locking is safe

1. All the locks are taken in same order (from root to end, forward direction), which means removal of newer nodes can block threads that are currently trying to remove older node, but there is no loop for possible starvation - the thread removing newer node will block the other temporarily, do its job and then the other can continue. There is small incosistency in `Insert` where you first lock the node that will become the last and then lock the last node (which is reversed order of locking), but I believe you don't even have to lock the inserted node, because it won't be visible until `_end = _end.Next = node;`
2. You always lock `_end` before changing it (the node `_end` *points to*). You also hold the lock of the node that will become `_end` after the operation (`_end.Previous` if removing, not necessary in `Insert` because nobody can see the node until you publish it by `_end.Next = node` and only `GetEnumerator()` can see it, `Remove` would need to lock `_end` first, which it cannot, until you finish inserting).
3. `GetEnumerator` does not need any lock, because removed nodes retain their `Next` (which is `internal` - some `private` nested `interface` could maybe protect it even better a bit like `friend` in C++, but `internal` appears to be sufficient for your use-case). That means that even if you remove the node that is `current` in `GetEnumerator`, you can still safely iterate. Nobody can reinsert the node or modify `Next`. `current.Next` is always node that at least existed when you started iterating (as long as pointer assignment is atomic).

## Lines I deem unnecessary / redundant

1. `lock (node)` inside `Insert` - already described, `lock (_end)` is enough (and the order should be `lock (_end) lock (node)` to preserve the order of locking - forward).
2. `if (node.Previous.Next != node) return;` inside `Remove`. How could that happen? Not in normal usage, but if we consider that you could possibly call `Remove` multiple times for the same node. In that case, I would mark removed nodes by `Previous = null` and to make `Remove` not corrupt the state if you pass node from different list, I would change `_root + _end` to single doubly-linked node (add `Previous` to `BaseNode`) and make the list hybrid - null-terminated in forward direction and root-terminated in backwards direction (cyclic, starting with `_root.Previous = _root`). That can be implemented in such a way, that `Remove` could be `static` (not that it should, but could - does not need to access `_root`, all it needs is the `node`). That means that `Remove` could safely remove nodes from any list.

## Style / design / naming

`Node` is too generic for global space (and you should use `namespace`). I would make it `public` nested (I hope you can still make the list implement `IEnumerable<Node>`), have `Next` and `Previous private`, add `private interface` to `Node` with `Insert` and `Remove` that will be called by the list (and `Insert` only as `Insert => _root.Insert(value)` and `Remove => ((INode)node).Remove()`, while having `INode _root` as well as `Next` and `Previous`) to protect everybody including yourself from modifying `Next`/`Previous` in unacceptable way.

P.S.: Having `Next` typed as `Node` (as you currently have) may be better for performance (needing `((INode)_root).Insert(value)` which is safe cast, compiler knows it is valid). The originally proposed version (having `INode`-typed `Next`) would need casting in `GetEnumerator` that would have to be runtime-checked.

Comment: P.P.S.: Document your code, describe what it does and how it does it. There are many doubly-linked lists (null-terminated, cyclic and hybrid and all can have zero, one or two embedded nodes, which together means 9 possible implementations, although not all combinations are used, still a lot of possible versions).

Comment: I have **very bad feeling** about `lock (node.Previous)` (concurrent `Remove` could change it), but I also think, that this lock is actually redundant and the `lock (node) if (node.Next != null) lock (node.Next)` saves the code. Alternative could be `lock (node) lock (node.Previous)`, which should also work. I will give it some more time, this is not trivial (so, the answer could as well be: don't try to be too clever, use safer but surely secure locking).